# Does mysql supports two default timestamp columns in a table now?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, default

I've two columns in my tables in mysql db:
1. ins_ts 
2. upd_ts

- 1st column should get a default timestamp whenever a row is inserted
- 2nd column should be updated with the default current timestamp each time a row is updated.

So I need both column to have a default value.

That's what I'm trying to do:

```
alter table test MODIFY ins_ts timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
alter table test MODIFY upd_ts timestamp ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

1st works but 2nd one gives me following error:

```
Error Code: 1293. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column
with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

I had read somewhere that mysql now supports two default timestamp columns, but here it doesn't works.

Please suggest is there any way to achieve the same functionality.

Thanks

Comment: What version are you using? Did you check [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html)? If you have a version before 5.6.5 use a trigger to modify `upd_ts` on update

Comment: Its working in higher version, while another problem is when I tried updating in one of the table like this:
alter table category_xref MODIFY ins_ts timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

I get this error:
Error Code: 1138. Invalid use of NULL value

My table desc is:


'CREATE TABLE `category_xref` (
  `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ins_login` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upd_login` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ins_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `upd_ts` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: The `TIMESTAMP` column is a quirky artifact from MySQL's early days and really should be avoided. `DATETIME` is the way to go here. If you need a trigger to automatically populate the values that's unfortunate, usually the application layer handles filling these in. All you need to do is add `NOW()` as the argument for that column on `INSERT`.